# Can Banana, port of kibana be used with Mysql for data Visualization

Tags: mysql, apache, solr, kibana, banana

I have installed Apache SOLR and Banana on a single machine for data visualization requirements. Some parts of MySql data is not indexed in apache SOLR. How can i use Banana to generate data visualization of my non indexed database.

Comment: I believe currently there is no support for connecting Banana to MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @aadel, can you tell me the idea if is there any other solution.

Comment: you can either index the data you need to visualize in Solr or use a classical BI tool to do the work in the relational world. Just a note, if the fields are "stored" in Solr but not "indexed", you can still visualize in Banana but you just won't be able to search them.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you.